# For comprehension and number of function creation

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

Recently I had an interview for Scala Developer position. I was asked such question

```
// matrix 100x100 (content unimportant)

val matrix = Seq.tabulate(100, 100) { case (x, y) => x + y }

// A

for {

   row <- matrix

   elem <- row

} print(elem)

// B

val func = print _
for {

   row <- matrix

   elem <- row

} func(elem)
```

and the question was: Which implementation, A or B, is more efficent?

We all know that *for comprehensions* can be translated to

```
// A

matrix.foreach(row => row.foreach(elem => print(elem)))

// B

matrix.foreach(row => row.foreach(func))
```

B can be written as `matrix.foreach(row => row.foreach(print _))`

Supposedly correct answer is B, because A will create function `print` 100 times more.

I have checked Language Specification but still fail to understand the answer. Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: I suppose it's because the `A` answer is creating 100 anonymous functions (`elem => print(elem)`), while the `B` answer is reusing the same function, but it's just a guess, I could be easily wrong.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. I mistakenly took `elem => print(elem)` for pattern matching comprehension while it's a function `Int => Unit`. Silly me. Stupid mistake.

Comment: As I said I can't really understand why too so treat my comments as guesses. I was thinking about how the Scala compiler treats anonymous functions, in the end they're just functions and probably after each `foreach` iteration they must be build again from the ground up (e.g. they're not stored anywhere, they get lost after they've been used), that's why using an already defined function is (probably slightly) more efficient. Anyway this is a first for me too, better wait for somebody with more experience and knowledge than me.

Comment: as I remember it creates `Function1[Any, Unit] { def apply(x: Any): Unit = print(x) }`

Comment: Yes if I'm not mistaken that should be the signature, anyway as you said, that's no param matching, the `=>` here defines an anonymous function with type `Int => Unit`.

Comment: I think we can explaint it with
`for(i <- 1 to 5) {
 val func = new Function1[Any, Unit] {
  println("Creating new function")
  def apply(x: Any): Unit = println(x)
 }
 func(i)
}`

That would explain the answer.

Comment: This interview question is weird. 95% of the execution time is probably spent in the syscalls - hard to measure any difference there.

Comment: Point of the question was probably checking whether I am aware of how anonymous function works.

Comment: I guess A is more efficient. `func(elem)` invokes `Function1.apply()`, then it invokes `print` inside of `Function1.apply()`. So It has one more method invocation than directly calls `print()`. But I'm not sure...

Comment: It's a bit picky for a Scala question. I can't imagine it predicting the usefulness of a candidate. My first response would be say let's measure it, I think!

Comment: I don't know. Still waiting for response. Maybe failing on that question will the reason to not getting it in the end :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short:

Example A is faster in theory, in practice you shouldn't be able to measure any difference though.

Long answer:

As you already found out

```
for {xs <- xxs; x <- xs} f(x)
```

is translated to

```
xxs.foreach(xs => xs.foreach(x => f(x)))
```

This is explained in §6.19 SLS:

> A for loop
>
> ```
> for ( p <- e; p' <- e' ... ) e''
> ```
>
> where ... is a (possibly empty) sequence of generators, definitions, or guards, is translated to
>
> ```
> e .foreach { case p => for ( p' <- e' ... ) e'' }
> ```

Now when one writes a function literal, one gets a new instance every time the function needs to be called (§6.23 SLS). This means that

```
xs.foreach(x => f(x))
```

is equivalent to

```
xs.foreach(new scala.Function1 { def apply(x: T) = f(x)})
```

When you introduce a local function type

```
val g = f _; xxs.foreach(xs => xs.foreach(x => g(x)))
```

you are not introducing an optimization because you still pass a function literal to `foreach`. In fact the code is slower because the inner `foreach` is translated to

```
xs.foreach(new scala.Function1 { def apply(x: T) = g.apply(x) })
```

where an additional call to the `apply` method of `g` happens. Though, you can optimize when you write

```
val g = f _; xxs.foreach(xs => xs.foreach(g))
```

because the inner `foreach` now is translated to

```
xs.foreach(g())
```

which means that the function `g` itself is passed to `foreach`.

This would mean that B is faster in theory, because no anonymous function needs to be created each time the body of the for comprehension is executed. However, the optimization mentioned above (that the function is directly passed to `foreach`) is not applied on for comprehensions, because as the spec says the translation includes the creation of function literals, therefore there are always unnecessary function objects created (here I must say that the compiler could optimize that as well, but it doesn't because optimization of for comprehensions is difficult and does still not happen in 2.11). All in all it means that A is more efficient but B would be more efficient if it is written without a for comprehension (and no function literal is created for the innermost function).

Nevertheless, all of these rules can only be applied in theory, because in practice there is the backend of scalac and the JVM itself which both can do optimizations - not to mention optimizations that are done by the CPU. Furthermore your example contains a syscall that is executed on every iteration - it is probably the most expensive operation here that outweighs everything else.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!  I had incorrectly assumed that `for` would avoid the unnecessary literals.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. So all our assumptions were right. In theory, answer B is still more efficent. We are not commenting about pracitcal aspect of the question :)

Comment: No, in theory A is more efficient. See my second last paragraph.

Comment: Ah, yes. Because for comprehensions are translated automatically. If we had written the `foreach` version by ourselves in this optimized version then it would have been faster. Sorry, I must have skipped last sentence :) So it means that my answer `A` was correct after all ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with *sschaef* and say that `A` is the more efficient option.

Looking at the generated class files we get the following anonymous functions and their apply methods:

```
MethodA:
  anonfun$2            -- row => row.foreach(new anonfun$2$$anonfun$1)
  anonfun$2$$anonfun$1 -- elem => print(elem)
```

i.e. `matrix.foreach(row => row.foreach(elem => print(elem)))`

```
MethodB:
  anonfun$3            -- x => print(x)
  anonfun$4            -- row => row.foreach(new anonfun$4$$anonfun$2)
  anonfun$4$$anonfun$2 -- elem => func(elem)
```

i.e. `matrix.foreach(row => row.foreach(elem => func(elem)))`
where `func` is just another indirection before calling to `print`. In addition `func` needs to be looked up, i.e. through a method call on an instance (`this.func()`) for each row.

So for Method B, 1 extra object is created (`func`) and there are `# of elem` additional function calls.

The most efficient option would be

```
matrix.foreach(row => row.foreach(func))
```

as this has the least number of objects created and does exactly as you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

## Benchmark

### Summary

Method A is nearly 30% faster than method B.

Link to code: https://gist.github.com/ziggystar/490f693bc39d1396ef8d

### Implementation Details

I added method C (two while loops) and D (fold, sum). I also increased the size of the matrix and used an `IndexedSeq` instead. Also I replaced the `print` with something less heavy (sum all entries).

Strangely the `while` construct is not the fastest. But if one uses `Array` instead of `IndexedSeq` it becomes the fastest by a large margin (factor 5, no boxing anymore). Using explicitly boxed integers, methods A, B, C are all equally fast. In particular they are faster by 50% compared to the implicitly boxed versions of A, B.

### Results

```
A
4.907797735
4.369745787
4.375195012000001
4.7421321800000005
4.35150636
B
5.955951859000001
5.925475619
5.939570085000001
5.955592247
5.939672226000001
C
5.991946029
5.960122757000001
5.970733164
6.025532582
6.04999499
D
9.278486201
9.265983922
9.228320372
9.255641645
9.22281905
verify results
999000000
999000000
999000000
999000000

>$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.0 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

### Code excerpt

```
val matrix = IndexedSeq.tabulate(1000, 1000) { case (x, y) => x + y }

def variantA(): Int = {
  var r = 0
  for {
    row <- matrix
    elem <- row
  }{
    r += elem
  }
  r
}

def variantB(): Int = {
  var r = 0
  val f = (x:Int) => r += x
  for {
    row <- matrix
    elem <- row
  } f(elem)
  r
}

def variantC(): Int = {
  var r = 0
  var i1 = 0
  while(i1 < matrix.size){
    var i2 = 0
    val row = matrix(i1)
    while(i2 < row.size){
      r += row(i2)
      i2 += 1
    }
    i1 += 1
  }
  r
}

def variantD(): Int = matrix.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.sum)
```